# Jeito mais simples de gerar um PDF de um input HTML, client-side

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

Estou desenvolvendo um material didático em linguagem web, e dentro dele, existem alguns exercícios em que o usuário tem que responder algumas perguntas, escrevendo uma breve dissertação dentro de um Text Area.

Depois de finalizar o exercício, gostaria que um PDF fosse gerado com esse texto que ele escreveu, para que ele possa baixar em seu computador. Como podem perceber, a solução pode ser client-side.

Ele não precisa ser gerado do zero. Nesse caso, eu posso desenvolver um template PDF, já com estilo, fontes, cores, marcas etc. e um campo, que será preenchido por esse input do usuário.

Faço essa pergunta porque o procedimento é realmente bem simples, não é um formulário completo, o PDF não terá múltiplas páginas, o JavaScript não vai precisar necessariamente estilizar o PDF...

Entretanto, não encontro soluções simples, o jsPDF me pareceu um pouco complicado para minha solicitação...

Comment: Por que acha o jsPDF um pouco complicado?

Answer (score 4):

Tirando o [**projeto jsPDF**](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html), não existe mais nada por aí que sirva o teu requisito de gerar PDFs no lado do cliente.

Não sei porque achas o jsPDF complicado, afinal de contas, iniciar e terminar um documento está bastante simples quando comparado com ferramentas mais avançadas *server-side*:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();                         // novo documento

doc.text("Bastante simples o jsPDF!", 35, 25); // algum texto

doc.save('verifica.pdf');                      // download
```

Comment: Eu estava mostrando repulsa ao jsPDF pq estava com muitos problemas com ele, e estava com o tempo bem curto... Mas você tem razão, ele é bem simples. Infelizmente ele trabalho de uma forma bem linear... Mas ele é otimo. Obrigado!

Comment: Se utilizaste outra forma para lidar com o teu problema, aproveita e coloca como resposta para ajudar futuros leitores com o mesmo problema :)

Answer (score 2):

O mais simples que ja utilizei foi supostamente **jsPDF**!.

Eu acho que **jsPDF** encaixa perfeitamente no que precisas

Olha quão simples podes gerar um PDF com tão pouco código:

```
//Tão simples
var doc = new jsPDF();
// definir o tamanho da fonte...
doc.setFontSize(22);
// Adicionar texto
doc.text(20, 20, 'Meu PDF');
// adicionar outra pagina
doc.addPage();
// selecionar outro tamanho de fonte
doc.setFontSize(16);
// adicionar texto
doc.text(20, 30, 'Olá eu sou um texto!');
```